# C# Read a specific element which is in a XML Node

Tags: c#, xml

I searched a long time in order to get an answer but as i can see is not working.
I have an XML File and I would like to read a specific element from a node.
For example, this is the XML:

```
<Root>
  <TV>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <Company>Samsung</Company>
    <Series>13523dffvc</Series>
    <Dimesions>108</Dimesions>
    <Type>LED</Type>
    <SmartTV>Yes</SmartTV>
    <OS>WebOS</OS>
    <Price>1993</Price>
  </TV>
</Root>
```

I want to get the ID element in the code as a variable so i can increment it for the next item which i will add.
This is the code at this moment, but i can not find a way to select something from the item itself.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("C:TVList.XML");
XElement TV = doc.Root;
var lastElement = TV.Elements("TV").Last()
```

Comment: Try `TV.Attribute("ID").Value;`

Comment: Thank you @Sybren! It works.

Comment: @AlexandruFlorin it can't work, you don't have any attributes in your XML, let alone one called `ID`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A query for the last TV's id (this will return `0` if there are no elements):

```
var lastId = (int) doc.Descendants("TV")
    .Elements("ID")
    .LastOrDefault();
```

You might also want the highest id (in case they're not in order):

```
var maxId = doc.Descendants("TV")
    .Select(x => (int)x.Element("ID"))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
    .Max();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zZms1V) for a working demo.

Comment: That's correct. I am still a beginner and if i don't see any errors in Visual Studio it seems to be correct for me. Your solution is working and it was very simple:(. Thank you for the time which you allocated for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use like this to get id value

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\TVList.XML");
XElement root = doc.Element("Root");
XElement tv = root.Element("TV");
XElement id = tv.Element("ID");
string idvalue = id.Value;
```

also make your `<Type>LED</Tip>` tag of xml to `<Type>LED</Type>` for match

Comment: This solution is also work.Thank you for your prompt answers. :) You've been very helpful.